# Inspection Contigency - Form 35 (NWMLS)

Tags: united-states, real-estate, law, home

After a residential home inspection has occurred, and both parties have signed/initialed an inspection response (NWMLS Form 35R); What are the buyers options for recourse when the seller does not fulfill their obligations as stipulated by form 35R?

For example:

Buyer has home inspected and responds to seller with form 35R requesting repair/replacement of some arbitrary items. Buyer and seller agree to response. However, seller does not complete items before scheduled closing and/or has no intention of performing the agreed upon items.

Form 35R additional information:

Form 35R is an inspection contingency response for the greater Seattle metro area in Washington State, US. For more information on inspection contingencies in this region, I have found the following URL

http://www.realfx.com/blog/what-is-an-inspection-contingency.html#.VVDxGflVhHw

Comment: Welcome to PF&M! Please edit your post to add a tag to indicate the country - e.g. united-states? If so, is this form specific to one particular state?

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. I have updated the post per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the final walkthrough just before settlement, check to see if the repairs are made. If they have not been made the buyer has options.

- walk a way.
- renegotiate the repairs.

Talk to your agent about the possible damages you could collect if the seller is in default. The sellers agent will be reminding the seller about the damages. The seller might even owe the commission to the real estate agents.

Make sure everything is documented. You might even have to show up to closing to protect your rights and your deposit, which you want back.